# simple function that shifts specific element of a list

Tags: list, haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to figure out how to make a function:

```
    shift:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
    shift x (h:t) z
```

> Input: a generic list and an element x of the same type
>
> Precondition: element x exists in the list
>
> Output:
>
> > if n < 0, shift x left by n until reach the first of the list
> >
> > if n > 0, shift x right by n until reach the last of the list
> >
> > if n == 0, remove x from the list (always talking about the first appearance of x, it could be shown more than 1 time in the list).

Keep in mind that i have completed my delete function

```
    delete :: Eq b => b -> [b] -> [b]
```

that finds the first appearance of the desired element and deletes it. I could use delete inside shift i guess. Any kind of help is appreciated.

**[some I/O samples]**

```
     Main> shift 3 [] 5
     []
     Main> shift 0 [1,2,3,4] 4
     [1,2,3,4]
     Main> shift 3 [1,2,3,4,3,2,1] 3
     [1,2,4,3,2,3,1]
     Main> shift 6 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 7
     [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,6]
     Main> shift 'k' "skin" 0
     "sin"
     Main> shift '.' "factor.bit." (-2)
     "fact.orbit."
     Main> shift '.' "0000.1111.00" (-10)
     ".00001111.00"
     Main> shift "one" ["one", "two", "three"] (-2)
     ["one","two","three"]
     Main> shift "one" ["one", "two", "three"] 1
     ["two","one","three"]
     Main> shift "three" ["one", "two", "three"] 5
     ["one","two","three"]
```

Comment: If `n < 0` it shifts an existing value. If `abs(n) > len` it inserts at the start. If `n > 0` it deletes. Do I have that right? If so, then this is a bizarre function. Could you post some sample input and output?

Comment: `Int` is a type, not a type constructor.

Comment: @chepner excuse me chepner i meant just Int :P

Comment: @SilvioMayolo the sign of the value indicates if the shifting will be left or right. i just said that if the absolute value of the n is about to shift the element further than the length of the list, then it just put it at the start or end accordingly. Excuse me, my English are rusty, i hope you understand now

Comment: Would it be possible to make an attempt yourself?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i am probably trying that for hours now.. but nothing of what i wrote or thought about is worthy writing down here...

Comment: @White_Sirilo: yeah, but perhaps you can first try to implement a simpler function, for instance move an element one element to the right, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As @WillemVanOnsem suggests, you may want to try writing a function that shifts a target element one space to the right.  Even this simplified problem might very well be challenging!

See if you can implement a direct recursive version.  It could be similar in structure to your `delete` function, except it will *swap* two elements instead of dropping an element at the critical point.  (Answer at the bottom -- look for the definition of `simpleShiftRight`.)

Once you've done that, try working through this alternative approach which has the advantage that it will more easily generalize to solving your original problem.

First, using `delete` isn't very helpful, because `delete` "forgets" where the element originally was.  For example, both of the following:

```
delete '.' "abc.def"
delete '.' "abcde.f"
```

yield `"abcdef"`, and it's not clear how to use this result to, say, shift the period one position to the right of where it was.

Instead, what you'd really like to do is break a string up into the parts before and after the target element.  That is, you'd like to define a function `split` that works like this:

```
> split '.' "abc.def"
("abc","def")
> split '.' "abcde.f"
("abcde","f")
```

With this result, shifting the period becomes much easier.

For example, if we wanted to shift the period one position to the right, we could start by defining a function

```
pairRight :: ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])
```

that works like this:

```
> pairRight ("abc","def")
("abcd","ef")
> pairRight ("abcde","f")
("abcdef","")
```

and a function

```
rejoin :: a -> ([a], [a]) -> [a]
```

that works like this:

```
> rejoin '.' ("abcd","ef")
"abcd.ef"
> rejoin '.' ("abcdef","")
"abcdef."
```

and combine them:

```
> rejoin '.' (pairRight (split '.' "abc.def"))
"abcd.ef"
> rejoin '.' (pairRight (split '.' "abcde.f"))
"abcdef."
```

to get a function that shifts a character one space to the right.

Now, `split` can be defined in terms of the library function `break`, like so:

```
split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split x xs = let (a, _:b) = break (==x) xs in (a,b)
```

Can you implement the functions `pairRight` and `rejoin`?  They shouldn't be too hard, but if you get stuck the answer's at the bottom.

You might also want to try defining `split` from scratch without using `break`.  It's a slightly tricky recursive function.  If you start with an "obvious" approach:

```
split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split x (y:ys) | x == y    = (..., ys)
               | otherwise = split x ys
split _ [] = error "split: target not found"
```

you'll run into a problem.  It's not clear how to fill in the `...` because you've sort of thrown away the start of the list in the recursion.  Hopefully you've already learned that one way around this is to introduce an extra parameter to keep track of the list elements already processed and define a function:

```
split' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split' x ls (r:rs) = ...
```

where `x` is the element we're looking for, `ls` is the set of elements on the left side of the list that we've already processed (where we didn't find a copy of `x`), and `(r:rs)` is the right side of the list that we're still processing.

If you need a further hint, here's a template:

```
split' x ls (r:rs) | x == r    = (..., ...)
                   | otherwise = split' x (...) rs
split' _ _ [] = error "split: target not found"
```

Can you fill in the `...` here?  If you can, then you can define:

```
split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split x xs = split' x [] xs
```

Once you have `split`, `pairRight`, and `rejoin` defined, you should be able to combine them into a function:

```
shiftRight :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

that can shift a target element one position to the right.

If you get stuck, here's a complete definition of `shiftRight` and its
helpers:

```
shiftRight :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
shiftRight x xs = rejoin x (pairRight (split x xs))

-- alternative definition of split:
-- split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
-- split x xs = let (a, _:b) = break (==x) xs in (a,b)

split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split x xs = split' x [] xs

split' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split' x ls (r:rs) | x == r    = (ls, rs)
           | otherwise = split' x (ls ++ [r]) rs
split' _ _ [] = error "split: target not found"

pairRight :: ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])
pairRight (ls, r:rs) = (ls ++ [r], rs)

rejoin :: a -> ([a], [a]) -> [a]
rejoin x (ls, rs) = ls ++ [x] ++ rs
```

In this version, trying to `shiftRight` a target that isn't in the list or that is already in the rightmost position will give an error.  You might want to try fixing that.  (Note that `split` could return a `Maybe [a]`, yielding `Nothing` if the target isn't found; it also shouldn't be too tough to modify `pairRight` so that it does nothing if the pair is already shifted right as far as it can go.)

If this seems like a lot of bother for a simple problem, I guess it is.  In real code, an experienced Haskell programmer would probably write a direct recursive version:

```
simpleShiftRight :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
simpleShiftRight x (y:z:rest) | x == y    = z:y:rest
                              | otherwise = y : simpleShiftRight x (z:rest)
simpleShiftRight _ rest                   = rest
```

or this one that uses `break`:

```
simpleShiftRight :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
simpleShiftRight x xs = case break (==x) xs of
  (ls, y:z:rs) -> ls ++ z:y:rs
  _ -> xs
```

Both versions are succinct, handle all the corner cases, and are "obviously correct".  The downside, as previously mentioned, is that this version isn't quite as easy to generalize to your original problem.

The version above does generalize pretty easily -- you just need to replace `pairRight` with a more sophisticated pair shifting function.  For example, defining:

```
pairRightN :: Int -> ([a],[a]) -> ([a],[a])
pairRightN n (ls, r:rs) | n > 0 = pairRightN (n-1) (ls ++ [r], rs)
pairRightN _ (ls, rs)           = (ls, rs)
```

allows you to handle all positive values for `n` (i.e., all right shifts, no matter how big).  It's not too hard to further generalize it to handle left shifts, too.

Comment: thanks buddy you wrote awesome stuff, I will check them I depth later, I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

For you are new to Haskell, it's better to break the problem into simpler subproblems. One trick to solve your problem is:

```
thinking of "insert" instead of "shift". Pseudo code:
- remove x from the list
- insert x back to the list at the proper position based on given n
```

You already implement delete, lets take advantage of it. Enjoy simple code:

```
-- assume x is in the list, otherwise your problem would not make sense
shift :: Eq a => a->[a]->Int->[a]
shift x lst n = if n == 0 then delete x lst 
                else insert x (n + (position x lst)) (delete x lst)
```

Sub-problems are:

```
1. Delete x from the list: you did that
  delete :: Eq a => a->[a]->[a]
  delete x []          = []
  delete x (head:tail) = if x == head then tail else head : delete x tail

2. find the position of x in the list
  -- assume x in the list
  position :: Eq a => a->[a]->Int
  position x (head:tail) = if x == head then 1 else 1 + position x tail

3. -- insert x into the list at nth position
  insert :: a->Int->[a]->[a]
  insert x n (head:tail) = if n <= 1 then x : (head:tail) 
                           else head : (insert x (n-1) tail)
  insert x n lst         = if n >= length lst then lst ++ [x] 
                           else insert x n lst
```

Your precondition is that x is in the list, otherwise it does not make sense. If you want to include the case x is not in the list, twist the code.

Have fun.

Comment: simple, helpfull and enlightening answer, thanks for your time it helped me a lot.