# How to move an element inside a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, element

I am new to Haskell and I have been trying out some functions. I want to make a function that has as input a list (any kind of elements), an element (same type as the list elements) and an Integer.

So lets say we have the function move.

```
move :: Eq u => [u]->u->Int->[u]
```

So here is what I want to do. Everything is about moving the input element inside my list if it is a part of it. The integer input means how many positions left or right I want to move the specific element.

When my Integer is grater than zero (Integer>0) I want the element to move right for as many positions as the Integer.

When my Integer is lesst han zero (Integer<0) I want the element to move leftfor as many positions as the |Integer|.

Now if the Integer is grater than the positions available the element should go to the top or the end of the list.

For example

I have the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` the element `3` and the Integer `1`.

Since `1>0`, element `3` moves `1` position to the right so I have `[1,2,4,3,5]`

I have the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` the element `3` and the Integer `-1`.

Since `-1<0`, element `3` moves `|-1|=1` position to the left so I have `[1,3,2,4,5]`

I have the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` the element `3` and the Integer `5`.

Since 5>0, element 3 moves 5 positions to the right. But to the right I can only move 2 positions. So the element goes to the end of the list an I have [1,2,4,5,3].

I have the list [1,2,3,4,5] the element 3 and the Integer -5.

Since -5<0, element 3 moves |-5|=5 positions to the left. But to the left I can only move 2 positions. So the element goes to the top of the list an I have [3,1,2,4,5].

If my input Integer is 0 I delete the first instance of the input element in the list if there is one. Also I have a function to check if my input element is in the list.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
    checkIfElementIsInList :: (Eq u) => u->[u] ->Bool
    checkIfElementIsInList x l 
                        |x`elem` l = True
                        |otherwise = False

    deleteFirstInstance :: (Eq u) => u->[u]->[u]            
    deleteFirstInstance _ [] = [] 
    deleteFirstInstance a (b:bc) | a == b    = bc 
                         | otherwise = b : deleteFirstInstance a bc
```

Comment: The very same question was asked a few days ago, (with the same "helper" functions).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I guess you are talking for this question. The problem is that this answer only moves the element one position an a time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518370/how-to-move-1-element-of-a-list-to-right-or-left-in-haskell

Comment: Your `checkIfElementIsInList` function is perfectly redundant. Check the type signature of `elem`.

Comment: No: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49699485/67579

Comment: @cmaher My problem has also other stuff that I have already solved so I need this function. There is a reason for this. Sorry for not explaining.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I see. These inputs that are used are the same I have for my assingment. I guess he/she is a teammate from uni. Thank you.